# Training a Tensorflow model with csv files

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to train a machine learning model in tensorflow with csv files. But not in the traditional way where the csv file contains rows of (label, feature_list) pairs. I want to train with the files itself as data input. Each file (or 2-D array) contains arrays of features and should get a single label value of 0 or 1 corresponding to whether the data shows anomalies or not. 
To elaborate further on my data: I have many csv files of machine data in the form:

| Time | Signal 1 | Signal 2 | ect...|

| 0.00 | value    | value    | ...   |

| ... |

Each file contains readings of one machine. Some of them show anomalies in their readings and my goal is to have a Neural Network detect these anomalies. So far I havent found any examples of how to train in tensorflow with thousands of data values to a single label.

What I tried so far is to pack the reading into numpy arrays:

```
def pack_data():
    datasets = []
    files = ...
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    for file in files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        values = df[SIGNAL].to_numpy()[0:MAX_LENGTH]
        values = scaler.fit_transform(values.reshape(-1, 1))
        datasets.append(values)
    return datasets
```

This creates one big array containing an array for readings of each file.

I then transform it into Tensors.

```
training_features = np.asarray(pack_data())
    labels = np.asarray(get_labels())

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((training_features, labels))
```

The problem with my approach is that I would need an input shape of (6591, 1) for my model.

Is there any better way to do something like this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the anomalies occur at random points in your data or do they affect all readings from that machine? If the anomalies are random, you could label each anomaly point and train your model by data points

Comment: @Michael, if Shape is the only problem, we can `Reshape` the Tensor. Can you add the Error Trace, if it is resulting in Error. Also, please add the Model Architecture, using `model.summary()`. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael, How do you distinguish Anomaly Data with Normal Data. Based on that, you can update the Target Variable as 0 and 1, which then, will solve the issue with shapes. That way, it will be easy for the Model to classify if the Data contains Anomalies or not.